# React keep old state - new state not updated

Tags: reactjs, state

In a React project, I have a state `gameResults` with a array of games, and I have a function to get the list of games based on a query :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (gameQuery.length > 0) {
        axios.get(`/api/games/${gameQuery}`).then((response) => {
          const igdbGames: IGDBGame[] = response.data.games;
          const formatedGames = formatGames(igdbGames);
          setGameResults(formatedGames);
        });
      }
    }, 300);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [gameQuery]);
```

For each game, I don't have the cover, so I get the cover for each game :

```
const loadGamesImages = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < gameResults.length; i++) {
      axios
        .get(`/api/cover/${gameResults[i].id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          const coverUrl: IGDBCover = response.data.covers[0];
          const newGame = {
            ...gameResults[i],
            cover: coverUrl.url.replace("//", "https://"),
          };
          const newGames = gameResults.filter(
            (game: Game) => game.id !== newGame.id
          );
          setGameResults([...newGames, newGame]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error);
        });
      await sleep(300);
    }
    console.log("finish");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadGamesImages();
  }, [gameResults.length]);
```

Here is my problem : when React update the state, the old state is not there anymore. I explain : for the first cover, it's ok the new state has the first game covered. But when he make a new state for the second game, as you can see i get the `gameResults` state, but in this one the first game has no cover anymore.

Here is the result :
[image]

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of your looped asynchronous calls closes over the initial binding of the stateful `gameResults` - and `gameResults` starts out empty. For example, with the first Promise that resolves, these line:

```
const newGames = gameResults.filter(
    (game: Game) => game.id !== newGame.id
);
setGameResults([...newGames, newGame]);
```

have the `gameResults` refer to the empty array, so `setGameResults` properly spreads the empty array plus the just-added `newGame`.

But then on further Promise resolutions, they *also* close over the initially-empty `gameResults` - all the async calls happened before the component re-rendered.

Use a callback instead, so that the async calls don't overwrite each other:

```
setGameResults((gameResults) => {
    const newGames = gameResults.filter(
        (game) => game.id !== newGame.id
    );
    return [...newGames, newGame];
});
```

(also note that there's no need to explicitly note the type of a parameter that TS can already infer automatically: `(game: Game)` can be just `game`)

Once this is working, I'd also suggest tweaking your code so that, when the effect hook runs again, only covers that have *not* been retrieved yet get requested again. This'll save you from unnecessarily making duplicate requests.